# Pipeline filter modifies date every time I run the pipeline which prevent me from pulling only the last modified date to SQL

Tags: etl, azure-data-factory

Once a week, a file is generated to an onprem folder. My pipeline pulls from that onprem file to blob storage, then from blob to blob, during this part the pipeline filters my data goes to sql. Problem is, when it gets filtered the modified date changes and all the files in the blob storage are pulled rather than the one that got originally pulled for that week. I have attached images of my pipeline and the onprem files and what I filter for.
[image: OnPrem Files] [image: Pipeline] [image: Pipeline If Condition] [image: Storage] [image: sql pipeline]

Comment: Can you please clarify this: you will get a file every week. You are storing these files in a container from on-prem. Then, filtering out files with no data and storing the rest in another blob. Now from this, you only want to upload the data of latest file into your SQL. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: And also, from the above, is `daily(3).csv` the required file that needs to be uploaded to SQL?

Comment: To the first question, correct. To the second question, I was just showing the filtering process how it eliminates daily (4).csv. Let say daily(5) gets uploaded next week, I would like to only pull and filter that one without the daily(1) and daily(3) having their dates modified because every time I run the pipeline their dates get modified, hence why sql pulls them in over and over again. @SaideepArikontham

Comment: What if the next week's uploaded file (say daily(5).csv) has no data? Do you still copy the data to SQL? If yes, which file's data will be uploaded?

Comment: No, if there is no data it gets filtered out. As you can see from the first image, the files with no data don't have the same schema as the regular one so that is why I filter them out.

Comment: Understood. Can you also clarify this: Are you uploading all the files from on-prem to blob storage every week? Or only the latest file?

Comment: Only the latest one

Comment: Am I wrong to assume that you know the name of the file which you want to upload to SQL or not? (Since you are only copying one file from on-prem to SQL)

Comment: The file name changes weekly...so this week it will be like SalesWeekly_20222710 and next week it will be SalesWeekly_20220311, it changes every week

Comment: Or in my example it would be daily 4 this week then daily 5 next week and so on

Comment: So, your filename has date in its name. Are you going to trigger the pipeline same day as when the file is generated (say SalesWeekly_20222710.csv will be uploaded and processed on 27/10/2022)?

Comment: Correct, the file is uploaded at 11:55am, I intend to pull it that same day at 12:05pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instead of trying to proceed with last modified date of the file, you can proceed using file name instead.
- Since you have date (yyyyddMM format) in the filename itself, you can dynamically create the filename and check if this file is present in the filtered files list or not.
- Look at the following demonstration. Let's say I have the following 2 files as my filtered files. I used `Get metadata` activity (child items) on the blob storage.

[image]

- Since we know the format of how the filename would be (**SalesWeekly_yyyyddMM.csv**), create the present filename value dynamically using the following dynamic content in `set variable` activity (variable name is `file_name_required`).

```
@concat('SalesWeekly_',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyddMM'),'.csv')
```

[image]

- Now, create an array containing all the filenames returned by our `get metadata` activity. The `for each` activity items value is given as `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`.
- Inside this, use an append variable activity with value as `@item().name`.

[image]

- Now, you have file name you actually need (dynamically build) and the filtered file names array. You can check if the filename is present in the array of filtered file names or not and take necessary actions. I used `if condition` activtiy with the following dynamic content.

```
@contains(variables('files_names'),variables('file_name_required'))
```

[image]

The following are reference images of the output flow.

- When current week file is not present in the filtered files.

[image]

- When current week file is present in the filtered files.

[image]

I have used `wait` for demo here. You can replace it with copy activity (from blob to SQL) in `True` case. If you don't want to insert when current week file is missing, then leave the false case empty.

Comment: Thank you so much Saideep! I'm running the pipeline right now. I'll let you know what happens

Comment: I ran the pipeline, but it's not pulling data to the final sink. I pulled it to another blob storage instead of sql just so I can see the files, but once I get it working I'll route it to sql. If you have a few more minutes Saideep, here is a link to a google docs with my pipeline and process, only pictures so you might be able to locate my mistake: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10KnJDMZ7UU8N_jbBqkWqv40bs7Wf9FKn3aW7neIg_3c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You have said in the previous comments that file name would be `SalesWeekly_20222710.csv` meaning the date is in the format of `yyyyddMM`. But in the set variable1 where you are building the file name, you have given format as `yyyyMMdd`.

Comment: I made a mistake, the formate is yyyyMMdd, month before day. Is the new format correct?

Comment: Yes it is. In the final copy data where the case is true meaning `SalesWeekly_20222710.csv` is present among the filtered files, then in source of copy data (inside true case of If) you need to give the value of the filename parameter as `variables('file_name_required')`. I see that you have given filename parameter value as @item().name which might not be correct.

Comment: Or `SalesWeekly_20221027.csv` if format is yyyyMMdd. If this doesn't work. Please include the debug output of get metadata activty in the doc shared as well, if possible.

Comment: I have made the switch but It appears to be wrong. 
Name: file_name_required                                                                                             Value: @variables('file_name_required'). I've also put it in the google doc if my layout isn't clear. Also, feel free to write directly in the google doc if it's easier for you

Comment: Can you add the debug output of get metadata and share the google doc again?

Comment: Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10KnJDMZ7UU8N_jbBqkWqv40bs7Wf9FKn3aW7neIg_3c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: However, I can't debug the pipeline since I can't publish it. I'm guessing since my filename switch isn't correct it's not letting me publish

Comment: I changed it back to @item().name and debugged it, the copy data condition doesn't show up in the output, only wait1, I have put this in the google doc

Comment: I have [these files](https://i.imgur.com/fGHR1sA.png) in my blob. This is the [source settings](https://i.imgur.com/Zmc20ND.png) of my copy data (filename is a paramter created in source dataset). And this is my [sink settings](https://i.imgur.com/B2nhYyH.png).  The [debug](https://i.imgur.com/nVIKTSp.png) was successful

Comment: So, this indicates that there is no filtered file `SalesWeekly_20221027.csv` file (i.e., it is an empty file that came in this week). Hence if condition fails and hence goes into false case. What do you want to do in this case?

Comment: I've copied your source, sink and my debug was successful by again the copy data tool was utilized, that also in the google doc. The files I currently have in the input folder are not emply, I imported all good files before I started texting the pipeline, I included that in the doc

Comment: If the files are empty, I can do whatever your recommend, even delete them if we can

Comment: This files which I see as your input files are daily files i.e., not weekly files. The filename we are generating is `SalesWeekly_20221027.csv`, but the input files have name such as `NMSALESDAILY_20221027.txt`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Good catch Saideep, I mimicked my clients files while I was waiting for your response earlier. I've changed my set variable activity to @concat('NMSALESDAILY_',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMdd'),'.csv') and got rid of the txt file that was in the storage

Comment: However, I published it an debugged it and still no copy data activity. I'm posting it in the google doc for your convience

Comment: @concat('NMSALESDAILY_',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMdd'),'.txt') use this. Because `.csv` extension generates filename as `NMSALESDAILY_20221027.csv`. But for some reason, the file is named as `NMSALESDAILY_20221027.txt` (while others are .csv). Hence they don't match and again false case is triggered.

Comment: Should I still use this if I deleted the txt file from the input blob?

Comment: I forgot that we are only pulling for that day, so it wouldn't pull for 10.25 or 10.26...I said the file for 10.27 and put it in the onprem folder, I'm going to run the report now

Comment: If the file does not exist, then it wouldn't matter because current date's file won't be present and false case would be executed. The requirement specified is that, if a weekly file is non-empty (you are already filtering them), then data has to be inserted into SQL and nothing has to be done if current week file is empty (since there wouldn't be any file for current week, only old week files). The given procedure is exactly for the same. Correct me If I misunderstood any part.

Comment: It worked, THANK YOU SO MUCH SAIDEEP! hahah I can't express my gratitude enough